# ngModel Requiring Two Clicks to Check a CheckBox Sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've got an intermittent issue. I have the following markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="rs in vm.roles | chunkBy:2">
    <div ng-class="rs.length === 2 ? 'col-lg-6' : 'col-lg-12'" ng-repeat="r in rs">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.model[r.id]" /> {{r.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This builds a number of roles tied to properties on the model that are based on the `id` of the role. Something like `56caafa5-f667-4d8a-bbea-a5a0a6b3e8c0` would be the property name. **NOTE:** the property may or may not exist, but I have verified that the behavior is the same regardless of its existence.

What's happening is there are times you have to click the check box twice for the change to occur. The weird part is that if I use `ng-checked` instead of `ng-model` the issue *does not occur,* but of course this means I'd have to update the model by hand.

Is this a known issue?

Or is there something I need to change?

Hopefully I don't have to do it with `ng-checked` and a code-behind change.

I have reproduced this issue in this Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/gDDurHYY0EC7TMnuQ52t?p=preview

Comment: could you reproduce the issue in plunkr please?

Comment: @PankajParkar, I've added the link to the Plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

`vm.model[r.id]` for checkbox's ng-model evaluates to boolean it very strict mode by angular inner gears. For expected behavior you better explicit cast it to boolean on back-end (or in place you retrieve it from) or in special custom prepare() method.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code mentioned in the link, the script.js is something like this

** script.js **

```
    // Code goes here

var mod = angular.module('app', ['a8m.chunk-by']);
mod.controller('AppController', function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.model = {
    1: true,
    3: true,
    13: true,
    "97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8ca": true,
    "97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8cd": true
  };

  vm.roles = [
    {id: "97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8ca", name: "Role 1"},
    {id: "97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8cb", name: "Role 2"},
    {id: "97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8cc", name: "Role 3"},
    {id: "97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8cd", name: "Role 4"},
    {id: "97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8ce", name: "Role 5"}
  ];

  vm.modules = [
    {id: 1, name: "Role 1"},
    {id: 2, name: "Role 2"},
    {id: 3, name: "Role 3"},
    {id: 4, name: "Role 4"},
    {id: 5, name: "Role 5"},
    {id: 6, name: "Role 6"},
    {id: 7, name: "Role 7"},
    {id: 8, name: "Role 8"},
    {id: 9, name: "Role 9"},
    {id: 10, name: "Role 10"},
    {id: 11, name: "Role 11"},
    {id: 12, name: "Role 12"},
    {id: 13, name: "Role 13"},
    {id: 14, name: "Role 14"},
    {id: 15, name: "Role 15"}
  ];
});
```

In your template, for each section(say, roles or assignments) you are using two ng-repeats.

```
<div ng-repeat="rs in vm.roles | chunkBy:2">
<div ng-class="rs.length === 2 ? 'col-lg-6' : 'col-lg-12'" ng-repeat="r in rs">
```

For roles, the first ng-repeat `rs in vm.roles` gives `{id: "97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8ca", name: "Role 1"}`

The second ng-repeat `r in rs` gives `97547711-7024-4de6-be02-53fef122b8ca` and `1`

So, its `rs` which has `id`, not `r`. Thus the usage `vm.model[r.id]` is causing inconsistent behavior. I hope its just incorrect implementation and not some kind of requirement.

I modified the template slightly. I hope that it can be of your help

```
<div ng-repeat="rs in vm.roles">
  <div ng-class="rs.length === 2 ? 'col-lg-6' : 'col-lg-12'">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.model[rs.id]" />
            {{rs.name}}
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first `ng-repeat` chunks `vm.roles` into a set of arrays with a maximum of 2 roles per array. That's why the second `ng-repeat` is executing against `rs` and therefore each `r` has the appropriate `id` value. Needless to say, I think I can see how this might be causing an issue. I'm going to get rid of the process that splits them ( which allowed me to build 2 columns of check boxes ) and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have removed the chunkBy when testing it.